# installing powershell in aspnet:6.0 , sdk:6.0 images

Tags: asp.net-core, dockerfile, .net-6.0

I am trying to build docker container image targeting Windows os, for my .net 6.0 application/api

- while working in my company's network it requires me to install certificate into this image, to allow my traffic reach to nuget store etc
- in order to install certificate, I need to run powershell commands (not sure if there are any other ways)
- I am looking for guidance on how to install PS on these images ?
- I ran aspnet:6.0 image/container to check powershell and seems this image is not shipped with powershell

Question: is it possible to install powershell in this image ? how would I do this ?

below is my docker file and container - running powershell within it

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /
COPY ./my-api/certs/ ./certs/
RUN powershell Import-Certificate -FilePath C:\certs\my-certificate.cer -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["my-api/my-api.csproj", "my-api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "my-api/my-api.csproj" 
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/my-api"
RUN dotnet build "my-api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "my-api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "my-api.dll"]
```

[running image - to check if powershell is installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpB3z.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience with this, no it is not possible to install powershell in either of these images. A few months back I faced a similar problem, and the only solution I found was to use mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2022 as the base image, then install the .NET 6 hosting package to run your app. One major downside of this is that the Windows Server Core image is much larger than the ASP.NET image.

Below is an example of powershell commands executed in the Windows Server Core image to download and install the hosting package. Keep in mind there may be different versions of the hosting package you'd like to use.

```
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/7de08ae2-75e6-49b8-b04a-31526204fa7b/c1cee44a509495e4bb0bba49f52c719a/dotnet-hosting-6.0.7-win.exe -OutFile dotnet-hosting-6.0.7-win.exe; \
Start-Process "dotnet-hosting-6.0.7-win.exe" -Wait -ArgumentList /passive; \
del -Force dotnet-hosting-6.0.7-win.exe
RUN net stop was /y
```

You can still use the sdk image to build your app, but you may have to set up IIS in the Windows Server Core image to host your app.

Answer (score 1):

it helped for me

```
dotnet tool install --global PowerShell
```